# Duda con bootstrap y su descarga

Tags: html, bootstrap, slider

Estoy utilizando un código genérico para hacer pruebas, el código esta aquí: https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_temp_marketing&stacked=h

Lo copio lo pego en local y todo funciona correctamente el problema viene cuando cojo las URL de bootstrap descargo los dos archivos (el CSS y el JS con la misma version) y cuando los uso en local, los iconos de glyphicon y el slider de imágenes dejan de funcionar, me he asegurado de que he cogido todo el código y aun así no funciona no entiendo a que se debe el problema.

los codigos los cojo de:https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js y https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css

selecciono todo y los guardo en archivos separados en: C:\xampp\htdocs\proyecto\ASSETS\bootstrap

es algo raro porque el resto del css lo sigue cogiendo correctamente

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!--<script src="ASSETS/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="ASSETS/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css">-->


  <style>
    .navbar {
      margin-bottom: 0;
      border-radius: 0;
    }
    footer {
      background-color: #f2f2f2;
      padding: 25px;
    }
  .carousel-inner img {
      width: 100%; /* Set width to 100% */
      margin: auto;
      min-height:200px;
  }
  @media (max-width: 600px) {
    .carousel-caption {
      display: none; 
    }
  }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Logo</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Projects</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    </ol>
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
      <div class="item active">
        <img src="https://placehold.it/1200x400?text=IMAGE" alt="Image">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>Sell $</h3>
          <p>Money Money.</p>
        </div>      
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img src="https://placehold.it/1200x400?text=Another Image Maybe" alt="Image">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>More Sell $</h3>
          <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
        </div>      
      </div>
    </div>
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
</div>
<div class="container text-center">    
  <h3>What We Do</h3><br>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <img src="https://placehold.it/150x80?text=IMAGE" class="img-responsive" style="width:100%" alt="Image">
      <p>Current Project</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4"> 
      <img src="https://placehold.it/150x80?text=IMAGE" class="img-responsive" style="width:100%" alt="Image">
      <p>Project 2</p>    
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div class="well">
       <p>Some text..</p>
      </div>
      <div class="well">
       <p>Some text..</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div><br>
<footer class="container-fluid text-center">
  <p>Footer Text</p>
</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: No agregues SOLUCIONADO al título de la pregunta, si la respuesta que te dieron resuelve el problema entonces acéptala

Comment: tenia dos problemas y me han solucionado uno de ellos el otro sigo esperando por lo que aun no puedo aceptarla

Comment: entonces deberás esperar a tener la solución de ambos y evitar colocar solucionado pues así no funciona StackOverFlow

Comment: Gracias por intentar ayudar, pero tu edición no es lo que quise decir. He eliminado tu edición y he actualizado mi pregunta para que quede más clara.

Comment: Tu código se ejecuta correctamente, lo único que te recomiendo es poner los scripts antes de finalizar la etiqueta body. Trata de reproducir el problema que tienes, por favor revisa [Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable.](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: se ejecuta correctamente pero si descargas los codigos de sus url y las guardas localmente (codigo comentado) el slider deja de funcionar.

Comment: El error está en que llamas primero la librería `bootstrap.min.js` y luego `jquery.min.js`. Debe ser al revés. También debes dejar primero la hoja de estilos antes que cualquier script.

Comment: No me lo puedo cree que haya sido por el orden madre mia muchas gracias

Comment: Podrias poner una respuesta que sea la correcta y completa para el proximo que busque esta pregunta? si la respuesta que aceptaste no soluciona por completo el problema, dejale un comentario al autor de la misma, y no la aceptes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creo que Glyphicon no es soportado en la versión 4.1 de Bootstrap. Quizás el problema venga de ahí.
Actualmente utilizo estos iconos y son una alternativa bastante buena.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.2/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-oS3vJWv+0UjzBfQzYUhtDYW+Pj2yciDJxpsK1OYPAYjqT085Qq/1cq5FLXAZQ7Ay" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

En esta página tienes una lista con los iconos:
https://fontawesome.com/icons?d=gallery

Sobre el slider no sabría decirte...

Comment: Estás en lo correcto, [Boostrap no soporta Glyphicons en su versión 4](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/extend/icons/). Pero el OP está usando la versión 3 de Bootstrap.